# Invite more than 50 friends to an event with batch API PHP

Tags: facebook, events, batch-file, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I'm trying to use the batch API to make my users able to invite all their page fans to an event.
It's the first I'm trying to use the batch API and I got some troubles with it. Here is my code without using the batch :

```
$result = $facebookObj->api(array(
      'method' => 'fql.query',
      'query' => 'select uid,name from user where uid in ( select uid from page_fan where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me()) and page_id = '.$fbPage.')'
));

foreach ($result as $value) {
   $ret_val = $facebookObj->api($event_fbID . "/invited/" . $value['uid'],'POST');
   if($ret_val) {
     // Success
     $numInvited++;
   }
}
```

How to adapt this code to batch API to query more than 50 fans of the page ?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are the "troubles" you are having? Psychic debugging is a hard job ;)

Comment: Please include your batch PHP code in order for us to see your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> How to adapt this code to batch API to query more than 50 fans of the page ?

Since 50 operations is the limit for batch requests – just split it up into packages of 50, and make one batch request containing those 50 actions, and then the next one.

Comment: I imagine the OP is getting an error message to that effect... "You can only send 50 invites".

Answer (score 0):

sorry for being so late about the answer. My problem is that I don't know how to test my code.

I used your answers to write this sample of code. Can someone tell me if it might work, or how can I test it without sending it to production ?

```
//Getting all the likers of the page
$result = $facebookObj->api(array(
      'method' => 'fql.query',
      'query' => 'select uid,name from user where uid in ( select uid from page_fan where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me()) and page_id = '.$fbPage.')'
));


//If liker are more than 50 we use batch request
if($numLikers >50){

   // split array into several part of 50 users accounts                        
   $splitLikers = array_chunk($result, 50);
   // count how many arrays are generated by the array_chunk
   $countSplit = count($splitLikers);

   //Start a loop through the numbers of groups of 50 users  (or less if last group contains less than 50 users                      
   for($a=0; $a<$countSplit; $a++){
      //Second loop to go through the 50 likers in one group                                  
      for($b=0; $b<count($splitLikers[$a]); $b++){
           // construct an array containing the whole group                                
           $queries[$a] = array('method' => 'POST', 'relative_url' => $event_fbID . "/invited/" . $splitLikers[$a][$b]['uid']);

       }
       //Send POST batch request with the array above                            
       $ret_val = $facebookObj->api('/?batch='.json_encode($queries[$a]), 'POST');
    }


 }else{

    foreach ($result as $value) {
         $ret_val = $facebookObj->api($event_fbID . "/invited/" . $value['uid'],'POST');
         if($ret_val) {
            // Success
             $numInvited++;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Up ? Do you think that this script is correct ? Or do you have an idea how to test it ?